# Create a chart without xaml

Tags: .net, xml, windows-phone

I create a ColumnGraph in windows phone application using amchart and data from XML file.
I want to create the same thing but without defining the parameters `DataSource={Binding results}` 
This is my XAML code

```
 enter code here 

 <amq:SerialChart x:Name="MainPage1"  DataSource="{Binding results}"                       CategoryValueMemberPath="categories"
    AxisForeground="White"
     PlotAreaBackground="Black"
   GridStroke="DarkGray"  >
                <amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
                    <amq:ColumnGraph ValueMemberPath="dataset" Title="Column #2"                    Brush="#8000FF00" ColumnWidthAllocation="0.4" />
                </amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
            </amq:SerialChart>
```

This is my code behind

```
 public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            XDocument data = XDocument.Load("Results.xml");

            var results = from query in data.Descendants("Chart")
                          select new ResultModel((string)query.Element("categories"),
                           (int)query.Element("dataset"));

            MainPage1.DataSource = results;
        }



    }
```

And this is my XML file

```
<Chart>
    <categories>Wael</categories>
    <dataset>2005</dataset>
  </Chart>
```